# Kubernetes configuration to link containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to see if there are any example to create a Kubernetes POD 
which starts 2-3 containers and these containers are linked with each other but couldn't find any.

Does anybody tried linking containers using Kubernetes config.

Comment: I am looking at, how I can port a 3 tier application like this http://blog.thestateofme.com/2014/01/13/multi-tier-apps-in-docker-io/ into Kubernetes. If links are not directly supported then what is the alternative.

Comment: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#discovering-services

Comment: This tutorial explains how to create a php app (pod) and connect it with a postgres database (pod) in minikube (kubernetes): https://lvthillo.com/get-started-with-your-local-kubernetes/

Answer (score 15):

The containers in same pod shares the localhost, so you need not link containers, just use localhost:containerPort.

Comment: This answers the question the best. You don't need a service for containers sharing the same pod as joh.scheuer suggests. (Maybe at the time you did; 9 months have passed and Kubernetes is constantly evolving.)

Comment: This answers it but better answer is by joh. Should be "linking" pods and not containers in kubernetes.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the Kubernetes service (Proxy) https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/services.md#how-do-they-work.

Have a look how they work togehter: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/guestbook

To be specific, there is no concept of "linking" similarly to the way Docker does it. Every service endpoint is a fully qualified domain name and you just call it from one container to another, and every label on a container that can be picked up by a service endpoint can be used to direct network traffic. So, you don't have to do ENV["$FOO_BAR_BAZ"] to get the correct IP, just call it directly (`curl http://foo_bar_baz`).

Comment: As @Tony Dun's message implies, you can link containers together by simply including them in the same pod. They will all share the same network stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are speaking about single pod multiple container configurations.
 In kubernetes the small single unit is a pod. So multiple containers in a pod share the same IPC and multiple processes in different container can access via localhost:process port

Answer (score 0):

Pod is a basic unit of deployment in kubernetes.
You can run one or more containers in pod. They will share same network i.e localhost. So you don't need to specify the link url just specify `localhost:containerPort`